# Why Diana risk by jumping after Naomi saw her?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-2017

In movie *Wonder Woman (2017)*, Naomi saw Diana watching fighting practice, so Diana run away and jumped. But Hippolyte catches Diana.

[image]

Comment: What was the risk?

Comment: she is jumping itself is a risk to anybody, she hasn't became superhero yet.

Comment: Because she's a kid and kids jump? You don't need to be a superhero to jump somewhere?

Comment: "hasn't became superhero yet"... yeah, but it's quite possible that she still had above-human-child-level strength and endurance that would have made a jump like that only mildly dangerous.  She didn't get her powers from chemical spill or spider-bite, she's got them because she's a being that has superhuman strength speed and skill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the film's [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33560553-wonder-woman), excited by having seen the warriors practicing earlier, young Diana simply misjudged the distance to the walkway below.

> *Wily Mnemosyme caught sight of her and Diana coursed down another walkway, maybe a little too fast, and then she launched herself toward another path below. **She imagined herself soaring through the air just like the warriors—except that the pathway was just a little bit farther down than she’d assumed—
>
>   My worst idea. Maybe my last!**
>
>   Then something caught her by the arm and with a gentle upward jerk, stopped her fall.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Wonder Woman: The Official Movie Novelization](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33560553-wonder-woman)</sup></sub>